# Confused about collation in mysql

Tags: mysql, collation

In spite of all discussions about this subject, I can not solve the puzzle that I have with collation.

1. Created a DB with:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE Desk_Database CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
   ```
2. Created a table called Users and inserted the following data:

   ```
   INSERT INTO  Users
       (KlantGroep, TypeUser, Naam, Password)
   VALUES ("BNOF", "Manager", "André", "kkk");

   INSERT INTO  Users
       (KlantGroep, TypeUser, Naam, Password)
   VALUES ("BNOF", "User", "Ingrid", "ppp");
   ```

Now when using the following query it gives one row back, but it shouldn't find any row since `André` is different from `Andre`:

```
SELECT klantgroep, typeuser FROM processors 
WHERE naam = 'Andre' AND password = 'kkk';
```

What is it that I don't understand. I thought that `utf8_unicode_ci` will not throw away the accent on `e`, but it apparently does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour: "Andre" and "André" are equivalent according to `utf8_unicode_ci`. The accent is not thrown away, it's just that e and é are considered the same when comparing two strings for equality.

If you want to consider the two different you have to use some other collation, such as `utf8_bin`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to continue tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

See [this discussion here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mysql-utf-8-and-accented-characters-785471/). Based on that discussion it might help to set the collation to utf8_bin but there is also the possibility of a conflict with settings in the underlying OS itself.

HTH

Comment: I considered this, but I have no idea where to start in the OS.
I use Windows 7 Enterprise 32bit, Dutch language.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't allow UTF8 as the default OS encoding so I wonder if that's your issue. If you have access to a Unix/Linux server just for testing I would be curious to see if the issue went away. Looks like this might be a discussion more suited for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: With the table filled with the two given rows, I can not add a row with the naam 'André' or 'Andre' anymore. It should accept 'Andre', but it doesn't.

I am afraid I am not clever enougth to pik out the right stuff from the discussion you pointed me at. Switching to a Unix Server is not an option at the moment for me.

Is there a prefered collation and characterset when using Windows 7?

Comment: I believe "ISO-8859-1" is the default in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to continue tomorrow.